# Zooming to Polygon

Tags: openlayers, zoom, hyperlink

I have a list of records (states) in a table and each has a hyperlink, when a user clicks on the state hyperlink I need to zoom in to the respective polygon (state) on layer. How can I achieve this?

My layer inside the div is not central aligned. How can I make it central align?

Comment: way too general question. Where are your polygons stored? what do you mean by "central aligned"?

Comment: Central-align: The layer in the div is rendering right bottom corner. I want the layer to render in the center of the div.

Comment: Please read our [faq] and post only one question per thread.

Answer (score 1):

Some pointers to part 1 of your question:

- To zoom the map to a bbox, use [OpenLayers.Map.zoomToExtent](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.zoomToExtent)
- to get the extent of a polygon, use [OpenLayers.Geometry.getBounds](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.12/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Geometry-js.html#OpenLayers.Geometry.getBounds)